# How to control the encoding of html when using python win32com package?

Tags: python, html, win32com

In python, I use win32com to transform word documents to HTML:

```
from win32com import client as wc 
import os 

word = wc.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(wordFullName)
doc.SaveAs(htmlFullName, 10)
```

But the resulting encoding of the HTML is gb2312:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type  content="text/html; charset=gb2312" >
```

How do you control the encoding option of the resulting HTML?

Comment: <meta http-equiv=Content-Type  content="text/html; charset=gb2312" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Document.SaveAs method Office2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220734%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
2. [Document.SaveAs method Office2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084%28v=office.14%29.aspx)